# Cell reuse beginner? Tapping button in one cell affects another

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I have a TableViewController with a custom cell. When I tap the like button inside one of the cells, it is causing at least one other cell to have the like button tapped.

I am using Parse, and it is not affecting the actual like count of the second one which is being ghost tapped, but it is disabling the like button and turning it red.

I have read about cell reuse, and similar topics but am completely lost. I am new to swift, and if someone could help me navigate how to fix this, I can't find a solution on SO about Swift, and Parse.

**TableViewController**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:ChinTwoTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChinTwoTableViewCell

    cell.selectionStyle = .None

    // Configure the cell...

    let chinTwo:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

    var myVar:Int = chinTwo.objectForKey("likeCount") as! Int
    cell.countLabel.text = String(myVar)

    cell.nameLabel.text = chinTwo.objectForKey("name") as? String
    cell.bodyText.text = chinTwo.objectForKey("body") as! String

    cell.bodyText.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 18)
    cell.bodyText.textAlignment = .Center

    cell.likeButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.likeButton.addTarget(self, action: "likeButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

 @IBAction func likeButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let chinTwo = self.timelineData[sender.tag] as! PFObject

    chinTwo["likeCount"] = (chinTwo["likeCount"] as! Int) + 1

    sender.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    chinTwo.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            println("Worked")
        } else {
            println("Didn't Work")
        }
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

**TableViewCell**

```
@IBAction func likeTapped(sender: AnyObject) { 
    likeButton.enabled = false
}
```

The same problem occurs with the report button.

Comment: Two things: (1) post your cellForRowAtIndexPath code please (you appear to have code in your IBAction that really belongs there). (2) This isn't your problem but... You don't want to reloadData every time unless action on one cell really does impact the entire data set. This will cause a ridiculous burden as your tableView data set grows. Look into reloadRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: This isn't an exact asnwer to your question, but the one that I answered here might begin to point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31016503/xcode-swift-im-trying-to-create-a-like-button-with-parse/31030485#31030485

Comment: @BradBrighton I posted the cellForRowAtIndexPatch and so should I just delete that line for reloadData? The only reason I did this was because when I press the like button, the like counter goes up on Parse, but didn't on the tableview. Is there any way to update it in both ways without having to reload the entire data set?

Comment: I'll take a look at the new code... also, I specifically mentioned a call to look into on the reload: reloadRowsAtIndexPaths().

Comment: I tried adding the following, but it doesn't seem to have worked.     var selectedRowIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        
        if let indexPath = selectedRowIndex {
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
        }

Comment: The reload issue was ancillary; something that was in need of attention but not your primary problem.

Answer (score 1):

Due to reuseable cells, the same `likeButton` will be used on multiple cells depending on if it's shown or not. If you change the color of one instance it will keep that color when it is reused again for another cell. Instead of setting the color in the click method you should determine if the button should be red or not in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. So something like:

```
var likedRows: Set<Int> = Set()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    self.markButtonIfLiked(cell.button, atRow: indexPath.row)
    ...
}

@IBAction func likeButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
    ...
    self.likedRows.insert(button.tag)
    self.markButtonIfLiked(button, atRow: button.tag)
    ...
}

func markButtonIfLiked(button: UIButton, atRow row: Int) {
    if (self.likedRows.contains(row)) {
        button.setTitleColor(.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

And you shouldn't need the `tableView.reloadData()` call.

Comment: What would be in the hasBeenClicked function? chinTwo is a PFObjetct, and that is not a member function

Comment: maybe you can save what buttons have been tapped in a private list instead: ``self.clickedButtons.append(sender.tag)`` and then ``contains(self.clickedButtons, sender.tag)``. maybe not the most prettiest?

Comment: Okay, I have tried this but can't seem to get it to work. When I click a like button, it adds that cell to an array called `likedPosts` but i don't know how and where to check that, in terms of reloading the data / enabling and disabling the button / the color red? I tried `for likes in likedPosts {
            if(cell.likeButton.tag == likes) {
                println("It worked")
            }
        }` but that did not work.

Comment: Add it to ``cellForRowAtIndexPath``: ``if (contains(self.clickedButtons, sender.tag)) { cell.likeButton.setTitleColor(.redColor(), forState: .Normal) }``

Comment: it is saying "use of unresolved identifier 'sender'"

Comment: oh, sorry, it should be ``indexPath.row`` instead of ``sender.tag``. ``sender`` doesn't exist in this method :)

Comment: I'm very sorry that it is taking so long, and I really really appreciate your help. It is giving me a system error when I write that line... Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Comment: uh, it might be that self.clickedButtons is not defined. have you given it a default value? ``var clickedButtons: [Int] = []``

Comment: @materik how does this effect indices? If the OP was to try obtain the indexPath of  selected row that has been reused it will cause undesired effects. Subclass your cells and you can alter this easily in `prepareForReuse`

Comment: I commented out the cell change color line, and then it started working, and I tested with a println. It is correctly marking the liked posts now, but how would I get it to change colors? Then I will truly be able to test if it is not changing the colors of other cells.

Comment: @soulshined what would I put in prepareForReuse and would that be in the custom cell class I posted earlier? Sorry I am pretty new to Swift...

Comment: @AnthonySaltarelli if you don't care about indexPaths then you don't need to subclass, but at some point, in the future you might need it, and the more sane route would be to subclass it and prepare your cells for reuse, in other words set the like button to nil everytime you reuse the cell (scroll up/down). However, if his solution works for you and you have no need for indexPaths then do whatever works for you and your project. Subclassing is simple and in less than 10 minutes easily sustainable.

Comment: @soulshined by subclassed, do you just mean that I have a custom table view cell fro the prototype cell? If that's what you mean, yes I do have this class. If there is something else I have to do, I am not sure exactly how to do that.

Comment: @materik I tried your solution. I get an error for the IBAction. It says how there is the use of an unresolved identifier 'button' and 'cell' Did you mean to put these in another function?

Comment: Also, if I change the parameter to button: UIButton, then wouldn't I have to change the rest of the code inside the IBAction away from 'sender'? Sorry again, I'm still learning.

Comment: ok. the first issue was that I had copy pasted ``cell.button`` into the IBAction method, it should be only button, I have updated the answer. secondly, the sender will always be of type UIButton since that is the class you are applying it to but it doesn't matter if it's called sender or button so you can change it to sender if you'd like.

Comment: @materik I added these changes, but now it is having another system Swift error. I changed the parameter to button: UIButton and then changed all the 'sender.' to 'button.' and am getting the same error as the 7th comment on this post.

Comment: @AnthonySaltarelli set a break point when the color is set to make sure that the button exists every time.

Comment: @materik Would this be in the tableviewcell class or the tableview class? The button appears in ever cell, every time I run it.

Comment: well, i interpret that error to do with the ``button.setTitleColor`` and it might be because button is ``nil`` at some point. if you set a breakpoint there you can make sure that it is not. the error is a bit wierd though. i would suggest you also try to clean your project and restart xcode.